# Spring Security authorization redirect endpoint missing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

We're currently replacing our previous keycloak adapter authorization mechanism with Spring Security because we're updating to Spring Boot 3/Spring 6, and the adapter was deprecated.

Here are our spring dependencies:

```
   "org.springframework:spring-web:6.0.9",
   "org.springframework.security:spring-security-config",
   "org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client",
   "org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose",
   "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:3.1.1",
   "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client",
   "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security"
```

We found a security config that worked for all of our services except one. This is the basic setup:

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          keycloak:
            client-id: ${keycloak.resource}
            authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
            scope: openid
            provider: keycloak
            client-secret: ${keycloak.credentials.secret}
        provider:
          keycloak:
            issuer-uri: ${keycloak.server.uri}
            jwk-set-uri: ${keycloak.server.uri}/protocol/openid-connect/certs
```

Again, this works fine for all the other services.

Here's the Web Security config:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
class WebSecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain authorizeDvUser(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.formLogin(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .cors(withDefaults())
                .csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable)
                .headers(h -> h.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::disable));


        http.oauth2Login(withDefaults());

        http.securityMatcher("/internal/**")
                .authorizeHttpRequests(req -> req
                        .requestMatchers("/internal/**")
                        .hasRole("our_user"));

        http.authorizeHttpRequests(req -> req
                .anyRequest()
                .permitAll());

        return http.build();
    }
}
```

The "permitAll" part works fine, no authentication required unless you hit an "/internal" path. What happens then is that we get the authentication redirect to "http://localhost:8444/context_path/oauth2/authorization/keycloak" as you would expect, but that is answered with a 404 - Not Found.

I did enable debug logging and debugged through some of the depths of the Spring security filter chains. The debug logging states that it does issue a redirect to the authorization endpoint (obviously because we do get the 404 from it). However, the `OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter` (which should handle this request IIUC) never gets triggered. It does when I set a breakpoint for the services in which it works. To me this is a sign the redirect request is never received correctly.

The one difference in this service is that it doesn't have a database for session persistence, but this should create an InMemorySessionRepository which is enough for it because there's only one instance running.

What could cause this behavior? What can I do to investigate further, I ran out of ideas what to try.

I have seen [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76754916/spring-boot-oauth2-client-authentication-authorization-endpoint-returns-404) but it seems to me the only thing he does with the endpoint setup in the answer is setting the repository for it and uses the default redirect path, as we are trying to do. I did for completeness' sake add a client registration bean because there's one in that question:

```
@Bean
public ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository(final OAuth2ClientProperties clientProperties) {
    final var mapper = new OAuth2ClientPropertiesMapper(clientProperties);
    final ClientRegistration keycloak = mapper.asClientRegistrations().get("keycloak");
    return new InMemoryClientRegistrationRepository(keycloak);
}
```

but that doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

First **do not disable CSRF protection on OAuth2 clients**. You are configuring an OAuth2 client and requests to OAuth2 clients are secured with sessions (not access access tokens), which makes your app exposed to CSRF attacks.

Second, you use `http.securityMatcher("/internal/**")`, which limits your security filter-chain to this route only (and this is probably the cause for what you are reporting). For OAuth2 login to work, you should have as minimum:

```java
        // this defines wich requests are processed by the SecurityFilterChain
        http.securityMatcher("/oauth2/**", "/login/**", "/internal/**");

        // this defines access control
        http.authorizeHttpRequests(req -> req
            .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/oauth2/**"), new AntPathRequestMatcher("/login/**")).permitAll()
            .requestMatchers(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/internal/**")).hasRole("our_user"));
```

But if this `SecurityFilterChain` is the only one you expose in your app, you should probably remove your `securityMatcher` and let the filter-chain process all requests.

Last, I see nothing about [authorities mapping](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/oauth2/login/advanced.html#oauth2login-advanced-map-authorities) in the code you provide. You need something to convert Keycloak roles into spring authorities for `hasRole("our_user")` to work.

You'd probably save time using [my starter](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons) (and should probably follow [my tutorials](https://github.com/ch4mpy/spring-addons/tree/master/samples/tutorials) too)...

Comment: I introduced an additional security chain without `securityMatcher` to implement the "authorize all except the internal/..." URLs I want to secure (which was the intention) so the spring /auth shouldn't be secured anymore, but I still get a 404 (and I'd expect a 401(?) if that was the issue). It's more of an academic question at this point since the service doesn't even need security - but thank you anyway.